# Question between the proof of divisibility properties of binomial coefficient

Tags: number-theory, inequality, gcd-and-lcm

I was reading [this](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1975-27.pdf) paper by Erdos in which he derives that there exists infinitely many $n$ such that for any primes $p,q $ where each prime is greater than $2$
$$\text{gcd}\left(\binom{2n}{n},pq\right)=1$$
[image]
This is the page containing theorem 2 in that paper.
He says that from $(1)$
$$A(p;x)\leq A(p;(t+1)p^{r})\leq (t+1)\left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right)^{r}$$
Fact $(1)$ is,[image]

$\textbf{Question}$:-
I understood the part where $A(p;x)\leq A(p;(t+1)p^{r})$ but why is
$$A(p;(t+1)p^{r})\leq (t+1)\left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right)^{r}$$ ??

Comment: My bad, I fixed it.

Comment: OK, just to clarify : We give two odd primes and then the claim is that we can always find infinite many $n$ such that this binomial coefficient is coprime to both of them. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes and  Theorem 2 is required to prove that fact.